Inquiry: Determining Coordinates (X, Y) of 2 Points in a Triangle
I am seeking assistance in determining the coordinates (X, Y) of points B and C in a triangle. Here are the basic data provided:

The coordinates of point A (X, Y in meters, which may be negative).
The angle at vertex A (in degrees).
The height of the triangle (h in meters).
The orientation of the triangle (theta in radians). In the given example, theta is 270° (-1.57 radians). Theta ranges from -3.1415 to +3.1415, similar to a trigonometric circle. If theta were 0, the triangle would extend to the right of point A, and the height (h) would be horizontal.

Could you please provide guidance or a method to calculate the coordinates of points B and C based on this information?
Thank you for your assistance!
(This is for a program in C#, but mathematical calculations or pseudo-code should be sufficient).

As you mention, this isn't really a programming problem, it's a mathematical one, so doesn't really fit on this site. I would start by thinking about a line: if A is at 0,0, what is the formula for the co-ordinate h units away, at an angle of theta? Or perhaps equivalently, how to draw a circle of radius h, and select the point on that circle which is at angle theta.
